# Python - Adding new entry box when button is pressed (Tkinter) W/O global code

Tags: python, button, tkinter, addition, tkinter-entry

I know there is a similar question but I'm wondering how I go about doing this without any global code.
I want a new entry to pop up (as well as a label next to it) when a button is pressed.

```
class Options(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

    def add(self):
        new_entry = Entry(self)
        new_entry.grid()

def main():
    t = Tk()
    frame = Options(t)
    frame.pack()

    b0 = Button(frame, text ="Add entry", command = frame.add())
    b0.grid()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually does what you want. The only problem is you are calling the `frame.add` function instead of passing it as command, in button creation line by adding `()`. Remove those parenthesis and you will be OK.

```
b0 = Button(frame, text ="Add entry", command = frame.add) #no parenthesis here
```

If you want a pop-up, you need to create a `Toplevel` and put what you want in it.(`Entry` and `Label` for your case)

```
def add(self):
    self.top = Toplevel(self)
    new_entry = Entry(self.top)
    new_entry.grid()
```